# Error "You can't pop an empty literal stack" in theapa.bst

Tags: bibtex, stack

I'm drafting a scientific journal article and seem to have encountered a problem with the `.bst` file provided by the journal.

Here is a minimal `example.tex`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{theapa}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
Cite \cite{coles2011survey}.
\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{theapa}
\end{document}
```

And here is `bibliography.bib`:

```
@article{coles2011survey,
  title={A survey of the seventh {International Planning Competition}},
  author={Coles, A. J. and Coles, A. I. and García Olaya, A. and Jiménez, S. and Linares Lopez, C. and Sanner, S. and Yoon, S.},
  journal={AI Magazine}, 
  year={2011}
}
```

And here is the `.bst` file: [theapa.bst](http://pastebin.com/9fLPx7BC)

Sorry for not trimming it, but I don't know where the problem is.

The error I'm getting when I try to compile this (on MikTeX if it matters) is:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: example.aux
The style file: theapa.bst
Database file #1: bibliography.bib
You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry coles2011survey
while executing---line 1435 of file theapa.bst
(There was 1 error message)
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm afraid the bib style you're using is buggy. Are you required to use it?

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the error using the version of `theapa.bst` you've provided a link to. However, I do *not* get an error if I use the version stored at the CTAN (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex209/contrib/theapa). I therefore suggest you get a copy of the "official" version.

Comment: @egreg, Yes, sadly I am required to use it.

Comment: @Mico, I still get the same error when using the version you linked from CTAN.  I'm using MikTeX on Windows 8 if that means anything.

Comment: @Mico, I'm also not able to find any differences between the file I linked and the official one on CTAN (other than things like line returns).  See: https://www.diffchecker.com/r7b0mrd4

Comment: @Stephen - FWIW, I use MacTeX2014 on MacOSX 10.10.2. I'm afraid I don't use MikTeX (which runs only on Windows systems).